# Ion unable to parse json

Tags: android

I want to load and parse json using ion library but I have strange problem.

This is my code:

```
private void loadRandomUsers() {
    if (loading != null && !loading.isDone() && !loading.isCancelled()) {
        return;
    }
    String url="http://dev.ribony.com/mobileapp/get_json_random";
    loading=Ion.with(this,url)
            .asJsonArray()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonArray>() {
                public void onCompleted(Exception e,JsonArray result) {
                    if (e != null) {
                        Log.w("HATA","YUKLEME HATASI");
                        Log.w("DETAY",e);
                    }
                    for (int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {
                        Log.w("ADAPTOR","OK");
                        randomAdapter.add(result.get(i).getAsJsonObject());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

When I use this url for json datas

http://dev.ribony.com/json.php

Everything works.But when I use this url:

http://dev.ribony.com/mobileapp/get_json_random

My app is crashing,you can check these urls everything is same.

Here logcat:http://prntscr.com/49gd1o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because http://dev.ribony.com/json.php returns JSON, but http://dev.ribony.com/mobileapp/get_json_random redirects to http://en.ribony.com/ webpage.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.ribony.com/mobileapp/get_json_random isn't JSON. it redirects to http://en.ribony.com/.